# Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 Find and Replace ALT-F not working

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm using a demo of Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 and I've notice that they no longer open the Find and Replace in a separate window. The problem with this, at least on Windows 7, is that I can't use the normal hotkey shortcuts like ALT-F because its being intercepted by the main Window and brings up the file menu drop down.

Is there a fix for this?

Edit: this is referring to when the Find and Replace dialog is open.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the normal shortcut for Find and Replace - Ctrl+F? It's working just fine.

Alt shortcuts are usually bound to menu items.

Comment: I'm referring to the mnemonic hotkeys for find and replace options within the Find and Replace dialog.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't quite understand the question. It appears to be bug.